# search and replace string using python

Tags: python

I ave this code that searches for a string in txt file and replaces that with another string

```
import os

folder_path = '/path/to/your/folder'
search_string = 'old_text'
replace_string = 'new_text'

files_without_search_string = []

for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            content = file.read()
            if search_string not in content:
                files_without_search_string.append(filename)

        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            content = file.read()
            if search_string in content:
                with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
                    modified_content = content.replace(search_string, replace_string)
                    file.write(modified_content)

print("Text replacement complete.")

if files_without_search_string:
    print("Files without the search string:", files_without_search_string)
else:
    print("All files contain the search string.")
```

Not able to get the count of reports0

Comment: What do you mean by "count of reports"? Do you mean the number of files modified by your code?

Answer (score 0):

You'll find this easier to manage if you open the files in read/write mode. Also, Path.glob makes the file handling neater.

Something like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

folder_path = Path("/path/to/your/folder")
search_string = "old_text"
replace_string = "new_text"
files_without_search_string = []
count = 0

for file in folder_path.glob("*.txt"):
    with open(file, "r+") as data:
        content = data.read()
        if search_string in content:
            count += 1
            data.seek(0)
            data.write(content.replace(search_string, replace_string))
            data.truncate() # this is essential when/if replace_string is shorter than search_string. it's benign otherwise
        else:
            files_without_search_string.append(file)

print("Text replacement complete.")

if files_without_search_string:
    print("Files without the search string:", *map(str, files_without_search_string), sep="\n")
else:
    print(f"{count} files were modified")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the count of files modified by your program, I initialized a counter to keep track of that. Also, instead of reading your file twice, I used if-elif statements to check whether or not `search_string` is in `content`. See the refactored code below:

```
import os

folder_path = 'C:\\Users\\John Peter\\Desktop\\tests'
search_string = 'old_text'
replace_string = 'new_text'
files_without_search_string = []
counter = 0

for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
        
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            content = file.read()
            if search_string not in content:
                files_without_search_string.append(filename)
                
            elif search_string in content:
                with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
                    modified_content = content.replace(search_string, replace_string)
                    file.write(modified_content)
                    counter += 1

print(f"Text replacement complete. {counter} files modified.")

if files_without_search_string:
    print("Files without the search string:", files_without_search_string)
else:
    print("All files contain the search string.")
```